openpyxl delete_rows doesn't completely remove rows if row height is set
Any suggestions? If I ever the row height in openpyxl, delete_rows will appear to remove the rows, but when I save and open in Excel, the rows are empty but not all row information is removed. The scroll bar still scrolls to where the last row was prior to deleting. So "ghosts" of the empty rows remain. Sample code:
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Create a new workbook and select the active sheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active


# Write values into the cells
for row in range(1, 101):
    for col in range(1, 6):
        cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=col)
        cell.value = f"Cell {row}-{col}"

# Set row height
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].height = 14.4

# Unset row height
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].height = None

# Delete the rows
ws.delete_rows(35, 100-35)

# Save the workbook
wb.save('test.xlsx')


If I comment out both row height loops, it works correctly.
If either loop is included, remnants of the empty rows remain.


You find the reason here

This question is similar to: Can't get OpenPyXl to delete rows. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can't get OpenPyXl to delete rows isn't the question being asked.

Yes, the delete clears the cells however as the row dimensions have been adjusted (by changing the height) they now exist in the Sheet profile. The row delete function does not remove that from the Sheet. The result being that the workbook retains the rows to 100 defined in the Sheet with those above row 35 having no cell details.
You can fix this by deleting the row dimensions too.
for x in range(36, 101):
    del ws.row_dimensions[x]

Of course deleting the row dimension instead of setting to None would also affect the same change;
# Unset row height
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    # ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].height = None
    del ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row]


How much is deleting from the bottom a requirement?

@FrederickNord As long as you understand what you're doing it is not necessary to delete from the bottom. Most people delete rows using a count which theoretically makes sense, i.e. if you want to delete rows 1 to 5 you have a loop that counts from 1 to 5 and for each count delete the corresponding row. However if you do this top down it partially fails because as soon as a row is deleted the rows below move up to fill in, so after row 1 is deleted row 2 becomes row 1, row 3 becomes row 2 etc. 

 Therefore moving to the next count, 2 means the next delete removes original row 3 while original row 2 is skipped and remains in place as row 1. This happens with each alternate row as you go.
Reversing the count and deleting from row 5 to 1 doesn't have the problem as the row shift up doesn't infrige into the current row being deleted. The first loop method would work if you used the count only for the number of deletes made and all deletes were to row 1. However you can also remove the loop and use a single line delete_rows(1, 5).
